# Determining Pixel-by-pixel Catchments in ArcHydro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, saga, hydrology, arc-hydro

I used ArcHYDRO to prepare HydroDEM (5m) without sinks, Flow direction (FDR) raster, flow accumulation raster (FAC). As I understand FAC, value of pixel shows number of pixels that contribute to this pixel. Now, let say I derive drainage line from FAC (in raster form), I would like to link somehow all pixels that contribute to particular pixel in my drainage line, in way that I have separate contributing areas for each pixel in that drainage with clear relation to this pixel. How do I do that?

The main goal is to derive height difference between pixel in the drainge and any pixel that contribute to it and only to it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking to calculate [Melton Ratio](http://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/354013/thread/8cc937a0/#469f).

If so, [SAGA GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html) has a tool to calculate it in the [2.1 Beta](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/SAGA%20-%202.0/) release.

If you've never used SAGA before, it can be a little intimidating, but the hydrology tools are well worth learning, and it's certainly easier than figuring out how to get ArcMap to do things it doesn't want to.

Comment: +1 for SAGA. I'm not looking for Melton Ratio, but I found an algrithm 'Vertical Distance to channel network', which suits my needs.